# Incorrect satellite image tile placement

Tags: google-earth-plugin

Recently I started seeing the following nonsense with the satellite images in my Google Earth plugin:

[image]

The incorrect tiles fade in and out as I zoom, and at some zoom levels everything looks fine.

This happens across browsers (chrome, IE9, Firefox), but only on my machine. I've tried re-installing the plugin, but that didn't seem to help.

I'm using plugin version 6.2.2.6613

Does anyone know what might be causing this problem?

Comment: Does this just happen in your implementation or for all instances of the plug-in? For example, do you see the same rendering issue if you visit - http://www.google.com/earth/explore/products/plugin.html

Comment: It happens in all instances of the plug-in. I'm starting to suspect video driver issues, but I need to dig some more there.

Comment: OK, I'm guessing it is an issue with DirectX...Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this problem before and again recently.  The first time I was told it could be conflicts with the hardware accelerators but then the problem just went away.

Until recently I have had two instances of the plugin running in the same desktop application with no problems.  Then a couple of days ago I started seeing the problem again although it is not happening today.  I don't know if it would help but I would suggest rebooting your computer.

I've also wondered if Google was updating the plugin or the maps...

Sorry I can't be of any help but I suspect it will go away soon.

Comment: Here is the answer I got when I was originally having problems - 
"Anyhow, it looks like you have some kind of a rendering issue - perhaps with directx - is it just on one machine you are seeing that issue?
 
If so I would try running dxdiag.exe (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190900) and disabling things like direct3D and texture acceleration to see if that helps."

Comment: I tried disabling texture acceleration and that didn't change anything, so I'll look further into the drivers.

Comment: Is it still happening?  I haven't seen it in a few days.

Comment: I'm still seeing it, but I haven't exhausted my options for disabling parts of the driver yet.

Comment: This problem has gone away now, not sure what the real cause was.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a DirectX issue to me. One possibility to fix is to force the plugin to use OpenGL instead.

You can control whether the plugin usese DirectX or OpenGL by altering the registry key:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Google\GoogleEarthPlugin\Render\RenderingApi
```

The allowed values are:

```
0 (DirectX)
1 (OpenGL)
```

Try setting the value to use OpenGL to see if it resolves the issue.

Also, if it is a DirectX issue you could try disabling `direct3D` (as well as and `texture acceleration`) via the dxdiag as others have suggested.

Finally, you could also try disabling `write combing` on your card if it is enabled. This is usually done via the display properties for the card you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I found that problem only occurs when I have multiple instances of the plug-in running. Especially if I have it running in two different browsers at the same time.

Comment: Hmm. For me it happens even if I just have one browser open and one instance of geplugin.exe running.